# How to resolve SaxParserException in android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am using following code but getting saxparserexception. how to resolve it. when i am using following code it will give following exception.

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: unterminated entity ref (position:ENTITY_REF &@1:799 in java.io.InputStreamReader@406cdeb0)

how to resolve it please someone help me.

```
*public class MapViewActivity extends MapActivity
{
MapView mapView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInsatnceState)
{


    super.onCreate(savedInsatnceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myMapView1);
    //mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    double src_lat = 18.556019;
    double src_long = 73.822283;
    double dest_lat = 18.500487;
    double dest_long = 73.866900;
    GeoPoint srcGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (src_lat * 1E6),
        (int) (src_long * 1E6));
    GeoPoint destGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (dest_lat * 1E6),
            (int) (dest_long * 1E6));
    DrawPath(srcGeoPoint, destGeoPoint, Color.GREEN, mapView);
    mapView.getController().animateTo(srcGeoPoint);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
}
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 
{

    return false;
}
private void DrawPath(GeoPoint src, GeoPoint dest, int color,
        MapView mMapView01) {
     System.out.println("in drawPath");
    // connect to map web service
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
    urlString.append("&saddr=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString((double) src.getLatitudeE6() / 1.0E6));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString((double) src.getLongitudeE6() / 1.0E6));
    urlString.append("&daddr=");// to
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString((double) dest.getLatitudeE6() / 1.0E6));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double
            .toString((double) dest.getLongitudeE6() / 1.0E6));
    urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
    Log.d("xxx", "URL=" + urlString.toString());
    // get the kml (XML) doc. And parse it to get the coordinates(direction
    // route).
    Document doc = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString.toString());
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        if (doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").getLength() > 0) {
            // String path =
            // doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeName();
            String path = doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection")
                    .item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild()
                    .getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            Log.d("xxx", "path=" + path);
            String[] pairs = path.split(" ");
            String[] lngLat = pairs[0].split(","); // lngLat[0]=longitude
                                                    // lngLat[1]=latitude
                                                    // lngLat[2]=height
            // src
            GeoPoint startGP = new GeoPoint((int) (Double
                    .parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6), (int) (Double
                    .parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));
            mMapView01.getOverlays()
                    .add(new MyOverlay(startGP, startGP, 1));
            GeoPoint gp1;
            GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;
            for (int i = 1; i < pairs.length; i++) // the last one would be
                                                    // crash
            {
                System.out.println("in while");
                lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");
                gp1 = gp2;
                // watch out! For GeoPoint, first:latitude, second:longitude
                gp2 = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6),
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));
                mMapView01.getOverlays().add(
                        new MyOverlay(gp1, gp2, 2, color));
                Log.d("xxx", "pair:" + pairs[i]);
            }
            mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MyOverlay(dest, dest, 3)); // use
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // default
                                                                        // color
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}*

Comment: Probably there is an error in XML, you should check it.

Comment: when i give the url in broweser it will give correct location between two points. but giving exception at line  doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is related to the removing the old kml data for retrieving map information from Google.

[Why retrieving Google Directions for Android using KML data is not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo)

Answer (score 0):

u need to pass url instead of urlConnection and then use openStream on it:

```
doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
```