# displaying route path names

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, kml, driving-directions

//main activity in this class two errors shown below within the comments

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class NewroutepathActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     MapView mapView;
    private String US_API;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview); //or you can declare it directly with the API key


  Route route = directions(new GeoPoint((int)(26.2*1E6),(int)(50.6*1E6)), new GeoPoint((int)(26.3*1E6),(int)(50.7*1E6)));

//the obove line also getting error


 RouteOverlay routeOverlay = new RouteOverlay(route, Color.BLUE);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(routeOverlay);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    private Route directions(final GeoPoint start, final GeoPoint dest) {
        Parser parser;
        String jsonURL = "maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
        final StringBuffer sBuf = new StringBuffer(jsonURL);
        sBuf.append("origin=");
        sBuf.append(start.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
        sBuf.append(',');
        sBuf.append(start.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
        sBuf.append("&destination=");
        sBuf.append(dest.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
        sBuf.append(',');
        sBuf.append(dest.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
        sBuf.append("&sensor=true&mode=driving");
        parser = new GoogleParser(sBuf.toString());


     Route r =  parser.parse();// here getting error


 return r;
    }


}
```

googleparser classes here one error

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

public class GoogleParser extends XMLParser implements Parser {
        /** Distance covered. **/
        private int distance;

        public GoogleParser(String feedUrl) {
                super(feedUrl);
        }

        /**
         * Parses a url pointing to a Google JSON object to a Route object.
         * @return a Route object based on the JSON object.
         */

        public Route parse() {
                // turn the stream into a string


 final String result = convertStreamToString(this.getInputStream());

//The above line is getting one error



//Create an empty route
                final Route route = new Route();
                //Create an empty segment
                final Segment segment = new Segment();
                try {
                        //Tranform the string into a json object
                        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                        //Get the route object
                        final JSONObject jsonRoute = json.getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0);
                        //Get the leg, only one leg as we don't support waypoints
                        final JSONObject leg = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0);
                        //Get the steps for this leg
                        final JSONArray steps = leg.getJSONArray("steps");
                        //Number of steps for use in for loop
                        final int numSteps = steps.length();
                        //Set the name of this route using the start & end addresses
                        route.setName(leg.getString("start_address") + " to " + leg.getString("end_address"));
                        //Get google's copyright notice (tos requirement)
                        route.setCopyright(jsonRoute.getString("copyrights"));
                        //Get the total length of the route.
                        route.setLength(leg.getJSONObject("distance").getInt("value"));
                        //Get any warnings provided (tos requirement)
                        if (!jsonRoute.getJSONArray("warnings").isNull(0)) {
                                route.setWarning(jsonRoute.getJSONArray("warnings").getString(0));
                        }
                        /* Loop through the steps, creating a segment for each one and
                         * decoding any polylines found as we go to add to the route object's
                         * map array. Using an explicit for loop because it is faster!
                         */
                        for (int i = 0; i < numSteps; i++) {
                                //Get the individual step
                                final JSONObject step = steps.getJSONObject(i);
                                //Get the start position for this step and set it on the segment
                                final JSONObject start = step.getJSONObject("start_location");
                                final GeoPoint position = new GeoPoint((int) (start.getDouble("lat")*1E6), 
                                        (int) (start.getDouble("lng")*1E6));
                                segment.setPoint(position);
                                //Set the length of this segment in metres
                                final int length = step.getJSONObject("distance").getInt("value");
                                distance += length;
                                segment.setLength(length);
                                segment.setDistance(distance/1000);
                                //Strip html from google directions and set as turn instruction
                                segment.setInstruction(step.getString("html_instructions").replaceAll("<(.*?)*>", ""));
                                //Retrieve & decode this segment's polyline and add it to the route.
                                route.addPoints(decodePolyLine(step.getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points")));
                                //Push a copy of the segment to the route
                                route.addSegment(segment.copy());
                        }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(e.getMessage(), "Google JSON Parser - " + feedUrl);
                }
                return route;
        }

        /**
         * Convert an inputstream to a string.
         * @param input inputstream to convert.
         * @return a String of the inputstream.
         */

        private static String convertStreamToString(final InputStream input) {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        final StringBuilder sBuf = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuf.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(e.getMessage(), "Google parser, stream2string");
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(e.getMessage(), "Google parser, stream2string");
            }
        }
        return sBuf.toString();
    }

        /**
         * Decode a polyline string into a list of GeoPoints.
         * @param poly polyline encoded string to decode.
         * @return the list of GeoPoints represented by this polystring.
         */

        private List<GeoPoint> decodePolyLine(final String poly) {
                int len = poly.length();
                int index = 0;
                List<GeoPoint> decoded = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
                int lat = 0;
                int lng = 0;

                while (index < len) {
                int b;
                int shift = 0;
                int result = 0;
                do {
                        b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                        shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lat += dlat;

                shift = 0;
                result = 0;
                do {
                        b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                        shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                        lng += dlng;

                decoded.add(new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (lat*1E6 / 1E5), (int) (lng*1E6 / 1E5)));
                }

                return decoded;
                }
}
```

Comment: Hi, now there is a new google map version and GeoPoint class doesn't support by new api. can i use LatLng(double lat,double lng) instead of GeoPoint(int, int)? If yes can you explain me (lat*1E6 / 1E5) ? is it a double value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happened to me too. To solve it - in function 'direction', when you start to build the jsonURL string, add 'http://' at the beginning, just before 'map.google.com...'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are targeting newer APIs , that requires accessing the network not in the main thread. Change the definition of getInputStream() (At XMLParser?) to support networking in a seperate thread.