# Get distance from two location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, driving-directions, driving-distance

I searched so many links here.But i didn't understand full code. Suggest me a simple and easily understand code for driving direction between two location,and get distance from two location.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745316/1230123) post here, it retrieves JSON directions info from Google API where you can draw a route on the map between the two locations, or find the distance between the two locations (distance is in the class Route with `getLength()` method).

Comment: Hesham Saeed: Yes i already saw your link..But i didn't understand.I'll try..thank you........

Comment: Just follow the steps, you will get there, needs some time.