# Filtering information according to current position

Tags: android, google-maps

For example, I have a bunch of geopoints stored on a database (sql) and I want to display them to the user on the map trough a pinpoint, but I want only to show to the user the geopoints that are nearby the current user position, to avoid overloading the mobile device and the user attention.

I've been searching but I can't find any specific way to do this.
Thanks for the attention so far.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086570/get-distance-from-two-location) link.
It has solution for calculating distance between two GPS locations.

Now follow these steps:

Step 1:
Fetch current location using GPS

Step 2:
You can retrieve your location data from database.

Step 3:
Calculate distance between all locations and current location.

Step 4:
Give some maximum distance for condition. (i.e. shortlist location if its < 1 km or something.)

Step 5: 
Show those shortlisted locations in Google map. ([Reference link](http://onthefencedevelopment.com/blog/using-google-maps-your-android-applications-part-2-showing-current-location))

Hope it helps.