# Google Maps overview_polyline give wrong value

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My application is java google map web application. Get 2 points and send to Google
`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+saddr+"&destination="+daddr+"&sensor=false` , it give json. Then I have decode`overview_polyline` . My Problem is sometime it give extended value.

This is my decode part.

```
  public static ArrayList<Location> decodePoly(String encoded) {
      ArrayList<Location> poly = new ArrayList<Location>();
      int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
      int lat = 0, lng = 0;
      while (index < len) {
       int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
       do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
       } while (b >= 0x20);
       int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
       lat += dlat;
       shift = 0;
       result = 0;
       do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
       } while (b >= 0x20);
       int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
       lng += dlng;
       Location p = new Location((((double) lat / 1E5)),
         (((double) lng / 1E5)));

     //  System.out.println("==p==" +p.getLatitude());
      // System.out.println("==p==" +p.getLongitude());
       poly.add(p);
      }
      return poly;
     }
```

[image]

The black color mark , the rep didn't travel to that path. But it drawn like that. 
`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=6.95522,79.8864&destination=6.96165,79.8958&sensor=false`  This `overview_polyline` is `_pmi@}xqfNEkEM{@DREUOc@Wi@MOkBmCi@k@o@o@gA}@qD_DiDgD{MoN_DeDJEVGvBS`

this 2nd wrong path drawn[image]

This is my db sample data...
[image]

Please give some idea? What is an issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a sample origin and destination that gives this result?  Can you provide the encoded polyline that you decoded?  It looks like that follows the roads, so either you are requesting it or it is in the returned polyline.

Comment: It is unclear from your addition what a sample origin and destination would be to generate the example encoded polyline.

Comment: Updated with `_pmi@}xqfNEkEM{@DREUOc@Wi@MOkBmCi@k@o@o@gA}@qD_DiDgD{MoN_DeDJEVGvBS`

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is just an error for the smooth applied to the points, as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en):

> overview_polyline contains an object holding an array of encoded points that represent an approximate (smoothed) path of the resulting directions.

I actually saw how my path is drawed twice, so the last point connects with the first one, making a close path.

I guess that this element in the call output is just for a far-zoom use or something similar.

However, you can still parse the rest of the content as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316).