# get Walking route - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I used the method used on that link to show a route between two GeoPoints :

[Why retrieving Google Directions for Android using KML data is not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316)

I would like to know if there's a way to get a walking route instead of the driving route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require mode parameter value in your URL.

Check out [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters), different parameters which can be append to URL.

For providing Mode value in URL your have only 4 mode supported.

1. driving (by default)
2. walking
3. bicycling
4. transit

Supported mode value [documented here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes).

> Sample URL :
>
> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false&mode=walking