# Google direction API not responding 

Tags: iphone, maps

The google directions API stopped sending KML response from few days. Did anyone face the same issue?? Please help.

I am requesting direction between San Jose and Seattle.
Response: "no-maps-mini"

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer your looking for is here: [Why retrieving Google Directions for Android using KML data is not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316) .

In a few words : "This way of extracting the Google Directions from Google by parsing the KML file is no longer available since 27 July 2012 ".

Google recommends using json: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/.

Answer (score 0):

KML from &output=kml is undocumented on Google's side. You should not rely on it. Instead, you can use the Google Directions Webservice and get JSON or XML that you can parse or transform into KML.