# Not getting KML file as response

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, kml, map-directions

I am creating an application where I have to post to this url: [Url to get KML](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=22.583375060000,88.434077990000&daddr=22.491368100000,88.348189300000&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml)

The url is supposed to return a KML file, according to this tutorial:

[Tutorial link](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-part-1-get-the-route/)

But when I am hitting the url, I am getting a **HTML** file as a response which is very difficult to parse and is useless.

**My source code is:**

```
//Calling function to get the response KML
  getKmlFromUrl("https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=22.583375060000,88.434077990000&daddr=22.491368100000,88.348189300000&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
```

//This is the function to get the KML file and show it in logcat
    void getKmlFromUrl(String urlString) {
                String kml = null;

```
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                makeAToast("URL:"+urlString);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlString);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                kml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

               System.out.println("KML: "+kml);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//          // return XML
//         // return xml;


        }
```

After doing all these, I am not getting a **KML** response, instead I am getting an **HTML** response. The response (in logcat) is over here:

[logcat output](http://justpaste.it/1ido)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

KML response is not used anymore, google returns either JSON or XML, 
check below link :
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: Can you give me the link of a tutorial or at least an example of how the url should be formed?

Comment: sure check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316