# Android: I can find class in my package

Tags: android, eclipse, class, package

I'm following this thread: [Why retrieving Google Directions for Android using KML data is not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316)

but I'm stuck on a incomprehensible error. When I try to refer to my class RouteOverlay something goes wrong: I can refer to my previous created class(`RouteOverlay.java`). Here the sitution:

[image]

And if I try to insert the codeline:

```
  import maps.RouteOverlay
```

I obtain the following error:

```
 The type maps.RouteOverlay is not visible
```

I tried also, restarting Eclipse or Clean the project. I don't know what can I do!

Comment: Are you trying to import `RouteOverlay` from the same project or from a different project?

Comment: Same project. I import correctly the above class: (Parser, Route, GoogleParser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you are copying have a typo. The `RouteOverlay` class is not public.

```
class RouteOverlay extends Overlay {}
```

Change it to:

```
public class RouteOverlay extends Overlay {}
```

Comment: You are right! Sorry for the trivial question.