# mapView showing white screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, driving-directions

I want to show route between 2 geopoint in my mapview, but when I run, it alwasy show a white screen on my mapview. I use the example in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo) for my reference

here's my MapActivity class :

```
public class M_hospital_map extends MapActivity {

 // Map view
 MapView mapView = null;

 GeoPoint geoPoint;
 GeoPoint dest_geoPoint;

 // Progress dialog
 ProgressDialog pDialog;

 // Map controllers
 MapController mapController;

 GeoPoint start, dest;

 double latitude;
 double longitude;
 double dest_latitude;
 double dest_longitude;

 OverlayItem overlayitem;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.m_hospital_map);

    // Getting intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();

    // get all data from bundle
    double user_latitude = bundle.getDouble("user_latitude");
    double user_longitude = bundle.getDouble("user_longitude");
    double dest_latitude = bundle.getDouble("dest_latitude");
    double dest_longitude = bundle.getDouble("dest_longitude");


    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



    DirectionsTask getDirectionsTask = new DirectionsTask();
    getDirectionsTask.execute(new GeoPoint((int)(user_latitude * 1E6),(int)(user_longitude * 1E6)),
                  new GeoPoint((int)(dest_latitude * 1E6),(int)(dest_longitude * 1E6)));

 }

 private class DirectionsTask extends AsyncTask<GeoPoint, Void, Route> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(M_hospital_map.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Google Map</b><br/>Loading Route..."));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

        protected Route doInBackground(GeoPoint...geoPoints) {
            start = geoPoints[0];
            dest =  geoPoints[1];

                Parser parser;
                String jsonURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
                final StringBuffer sBuf = new StringBuffer(jsonURL);
                sBuf.append("origin=");
                sBuf.append(start.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
                sBuf.append(',');
                sBuf.append(start.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
                sBuf.append("&destination=");
                sBuf.append(dest.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
                sBuf.append(',');
                sBuf.append(dest.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
                sBuf.append("&sensor=true&mode=driving");
                Log.v("URL", sBuf.toString());

                parser = new GoogleParser(sBuf.toString());
                Route r =  parser.parse();
                return r;
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(Route route) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        RouteOverlay routeOverlay = new RouteOverlay(route, Color.BLUE);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(routeOverlay);
        mapView.invalidate();
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(16);
        mapView.getMapCenter();
    }
 }

 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
 }
}
```

And my m_hospital_map.xml goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0WM32EymVRmIVGz-fKJhPs2BT_sH1CZtV3QG54w"
/>
```

And I already use INTERNET, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission. Can u guys pls help me, tell me what's wrong with these code above.

Comment: Have you add map library tag in Android Manifestfile or not ?

Comment: witch api key is u r using debug.keystore ?

Comment: I use the api key from the 1 I generate from google by using My certificate's MD5 fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the key for MD5 fingerprint because nowadays Google create keys for SHA1 Fingerprint, and if you use key created with SHA1 fingerprint with MapView it wont work.