# Extract localities in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an interesting question :
I would like to make an android application using google map and I don't know if is possible to  extract all localities(cities,towns,villages) from point A to point B, and how?

Answer (score 1):

First, for the process of finding the route, you'll need to implement the "rout finding" yourself, as the default Google Maps API for Android doesn't offer this.

It can be done by querying the Google Maps online-serivce and parsing the returned KML/JSON file. See these two questions:

- [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685) (Old way with KML, now **broken**)
- [Why retrieving Google Directions for Android using KML data is not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316) (Migrating over to JSON, since July 2012)

After you have that working, your route will be a bunch of "way points" on the map. Then, take a way-point every X meters/miles and check for nearby localities. Use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) to do that.