# HttpURLConnection Error opening trace file: no such file or directory

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect to an url to get geopoints to draw a route in a mapview for my android app. However I get this error when I try to connect to the url to get the points.

```
URL url = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=59.690289,16.60868&daddr=59.6,16.60868&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
Log.d("log","url: " + url);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();          urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.connect();
Log.d("log","connected");
```

I have the following in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am running this in eclipse 4.2.2 on Mac OSX Lion using the emulator.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

Sorry, I left out some important info, here are all my permissions in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**EDIT 2**

here is the full error

```
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{markustenghamn.sfsfum/markustenghamn.sfsfum.MapHandlerActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at markustenghamn.sfsfum.MapHandlerActivity.DrawPath(MapHandlerActivity.java:166)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at markustenghamn.sfsfum.MapHandlerActivity.callMap(MapHandlerActivity.java:126)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at markustenghamn.sfsfum.MapHandlerActivity.onCreate(MapHandlerActivity.java:89)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-07 00:24:46.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7280):     ... 11 more
04-07 00:24:49.343: E/Trace(7297): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Can you check whether you are really getting kml out of that URL, because I get HTML out of it.
Also post the error that you are getting.

Comment: Full error added. I also noticed the html but I wanted to get this error out of the way first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to access Internet on the main Application thread, you are getting this exception. You need to do all network activity in a different thread. You can use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to accomplish this.

This is done so the the application will stay responsive even if there are blocking calls to the network. You may also want to read further [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I was dumb to leave that out, I already have that. I have updated my question, sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: Cool, that works. Thanks! As for my issue with the kml, it seems google removed this feature and found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316 in case anyone else finds this question and gets stuck on that issue as well.