# Google maps get coordinates on route

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, coordinates, routes

everybody !
Who can help me? 
I would like to make something like an navigator in android using google maps, and i need to know coordinates on my route on every xx kilometers (from start point to end point)

Just for example:
From point A to B is 1000 km, I would like to know coordinates on my route after every 200km.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same when I was working on an app last month, and I was able to get what I wanted from [this page in the google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON)  together with this answer: [Why retrieving Google Directions for Android using KML data is not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo) which gives you the co-ordinates for every little turn in the route.  So if you only want every xx km, you'll have to work out how to ignore a lot of points.